# Jbpm console not working - Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".WeldService:

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jbpm

I have downloaded the jbpm(jbpm-6.0.1.Final-installer-full) version and follwed the userguide to install the jbpm6. After installed jbpm6 using ant install.demo , i have started the service. I got the jboss server home :8080 after that i typed :8080/jbpm-console and i got error `Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".WeldService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:`

```
16:24:08,892 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".WeldService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049 Unable to invoke [method] @PostConstruct public org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup.assertPlayground() on org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup@2e1bb4a3
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:518)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.postConstruct(ManagedBean.java:174)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:291)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:107)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
    at org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.toString(AppSetup$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.uberfire.commons.services.cdi.StartupBeanExtension.runPostConstruct(StartupBeanExtension.java:83)
    at org.uberfire.commons.services.cdi.StartupBeanExtension.afterDeploymentValidation(StartupBeanExtension.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:241)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:229)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:207)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:75)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:31)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:369)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invoke(WeldMethodImpl.java:174)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:516)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.organizationalunit.OrganizationalUnitServiceImpl.addRepository(OrganizationalUnitServiceImpl.java:149)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.organizationalunit.OrganizationalUnitServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.addRepository(OrganizationalUnitServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.AdministrationServiceImpl.bootstrapRepository(AdministrationServiceImpl.java:149)
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.AdministrationServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.bootstrapRepository(AdministrationServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup.assertPlayground(AppSetup.java:96)
    ... 43 more

    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:83)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049 Unable to invoke [method] @PostConstruct public org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup.assertPlayground() on org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup@2e1bb4a3
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:518)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.postConstruct(ManagedBean.java:174)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:291)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:107)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
    at org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.toString(AppSetup$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.uberfire.commons.services.cdi.StartupBeanExtension.runPostConstruct(StartupBeanExtension.java:83)
    at org.uberfire.commons.services.cdi.StartupBeanExtension.afterDeploymentValidation(StartupBeanExtension.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:241)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:229)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:207)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:75)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:31)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:369)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invoke(WeldMethodImpl.java:174)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:516)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.organizationalunit.OrganizationalUnitServiceImpl.addRepository(OrganizationalUnitServiceImpl.java:149)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.organizationalunit.OrganizationalUnitServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.addRepository(OrganizationalUnitServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.AdministrationServiceImpl.bootstrapRepository(AdministrationServiceImpl.java:149)
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.AdministrationServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.bootstrapRepository(AdministrationServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup.assertPlayground(AppSetup.java:96)
    ... 43 more

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:31)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:369)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    ... 5 more

16:24:09,188 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
16:24:09,188 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 119786ms - Started 499 of 757 services (174 services failed or missing dependencies, 82 services are passive or on-demand)
16:24:09,422 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "jbpm-console.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".WeldService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049 Unable to invoke [method] @PostConstruct public org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup.assertPlayground() on org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup@2e1bb4a3
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:518)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.postConstruct(ManagedBean.java:174)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:291)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:107)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
    at org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.toString(AppSetup$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.uberfire.commons.services.cdi.StartupBeanExtension.runPostConstruct(StartupBeanExtension.java:83)
    at org.uberfire.commons.services.cdi.StartupBeanExtension.afterDeploymentValidation(StartupBeanExtension.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:241)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:229)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:207)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:75)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:31)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:369)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invoke(WeldMethodImpl.java:174)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:516)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.organizationalunit.OrganizationalUnitServiceImpl.addRepository(OrganizationalUnitServiceImpl.java:149)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.organizationalunit.OrganizationalUnitServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.addRepository(OrganizationalUnitServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.AdministrationServiceImpl.bootstrapRepository(AdministrationServiceImpl.java:149)
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.AdministrationServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.bootstrapRepository(AdministrationServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup.assertPlayground(AppSetup.java:96)
    ... 43 more
"}}
16:24:09,454 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011403: Stopping Persistence Unit Service 'jbpm-console.war#org.jbpm.domain'
16:24:09,454 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011605: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/KIE.RESPONSE
16:24:09,563 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015871: Deploy of deployment "dashboard-builder.war" was rolled back with no failure message
16:24:09,563 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011605: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/KIE.RESPONSE.ALL
16:24:09,578 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011605: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/KIE.TASK
16:24:09,578 INFO  [org.jboss.dashboard.cluster.ClusterNodesManager] (MSC service thread 1-6) Deregistering cluster node with id 3903
16:24:09,578 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS011605: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/KIE.RESPONSE
16:24:09,578 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011605: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/KIE.AUDIT
16:24:09,594 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011605: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/KIE.AUDIT.ALL
16:24:09,594 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011605: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/KIE.TASK
16:24:09,594 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011605: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/KIE.TASK.ALL
16:24:09,610 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011605: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/KIE.SESSION
16:24:09,610 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011605: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/KIE.SESSION
16:24:09,610 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011605: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/KIE.SESSION.ALL
16:24:09,641 INFO  [org.jboss.dashboard.cluster.ClusterNodesManager] (MSC service thread 1-6) Successfully deregistered cluster node with id 3903
16:24:09,953 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment dashboard-builder.war
16:24:11,185 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment dashboard-builder.war in 1623ms
16:24:16,193 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment jbpm-console.war in 6760ms
16:24:16,208 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".WeldService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049 Unable to invoke [method] @PostConstruct public org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup.assertPlayground() on org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup@2e1bb4a3
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:518)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.postConstruct(ManagedBean.java:174)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:291)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:107)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
    at org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.toString(AppSetup$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.uberfire.commons.services.cdi.StartupBeanExtension.runPostConstruct(StartupBeanExtension.java:83)
    at org.uberfire.commons.services.cdi.StartupBeanExtension.afterDeploymentValidation(StartupBeanExtension.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:241)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:229)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:207)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:75)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:31)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:369)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invoke(WeldMethodImpl.java:174)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:516)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.organizationalunit.OrganizationalUnitServiceImpl.addRepository(OrganizationalUnitServiceImpl.java:149)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.organizationalunit.OrganizationalUnitServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.addRepository(OrganizationalUnitServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.AdministrationServiceImpl.bootstrapRepository(AdministrationServiceImpl.java:149)
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.AdministrationServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.bootstrapRepository(AdministrationServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup.assertPlayground(AppSetup.java:96)
    ... 43 more


16:24:16,302 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014654: Composite operation was rolled back
16:24:16,318 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".WeldService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
```

Answer (score 3):

As salaboy said, this problem happens if you don't have a direct internet connection or accessing internet through a proxy.

If you don't have an internet connection, then follow the answer by dleerob.

If you are behind a proxy, then give the proxy details as Java VM parameters in build.xml

In build.xml, find the target named `start.jboss` . There are two `exec` commands in this target; one for windows and one for linux. Based on your environment, specify the proxy details in `<env key="JAVA_OPTS"` parameter using the following JVM options with your proxy and port.

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyname -Dhttp.proxyPort=port-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyname -Dhttps.proxyPort=port
```

Answer (score 1):

did you start the application without having internet connection? or are you behind a firewall. By default the application is trying to download a demo repository that contains a set of projects. 
Can you try again making sure that you have internet connection?

Answer (score 1):

The log and Salaboy's answer hit to my solution:

1. make jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/ant start.demo full working by following [1]. Then import/clone the two git repo: `jbpm-playground` and `uf-playground`. Now you can see two folders .index and .niogit under jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/
2. follow ant script jbpm-6.0.1.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/ant install.demo. Then copy the two folders from 6.0.0 to 6.0.1.

[1] https://community.jboss.org/message/851462

Answer (score 1):

I edited build.xml and replaced `-Dorg.kie.demo=true` to `-Dorg.kie.demo=false` in both places I found it, and only then ran `ant start.demo`

I got this information from [here](https://community.jboss.org/message/851462)

Mine started successfully after that.

Answer (score 0):

Making `-Dorg.kie.demo=true` to `-Dorg.kie.demo=false` will only make the build successful, but you will not be able to login through the JBPM web console (because the build process downloads few necessary modules through this parameter).
Better connect to a proxy-less internet connection or make proxy settings suggested by salaboy and then run the build.